# Check if the EMF record intersects with a specified area "Rectangle" using EnumEnhMetaFile

Tags: c++

Is it possible to Check the EMF recored intersection with a specific rectangle using `EnumEnhMetaFile`?

I tried to do it but nothing works fine specially with transforms. All I want is to check if the Text records are intersects with a specified area "Rect" from the `EMF`.

Comment: No, that's not simple.  EMF is a vector format, not a raster format like most images.  Something as trivial as a circle, a single record in the EMF, may need to be converted to four separate arcs when clipped by a rectangle.  The only reasonable approach is to draw the EMF in a bitmap, crop that bitmap and save it back.  With the inevitable loss of scalability, the resulting image will be in a raster format.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response...                                                                now my problem is still I need it as EMF... and let's say anything intersected with the destenation rectangle we can keep it, otherwise remove it.